# Why do multiple inherited types in a union not work in typescript generics?

Tags: typescript

I have two type declarations where one accepts strings and the other one only numbers as keys.

The `testFunction` does not compile, stating that the properties do not exist for the type `MyStringKeyObject | MyNumberKeyObject`.

Can someone explain?

```
type MyStringKeyObject = {
  [key: string]: boolean;
};

type MyNumberKeyObject = {
  [key: number]: boolean;
};

const testFunction = <T extends MyStringKeyObject | MyNumberKeyObject>(
  generic: T
): void => {
  generic[1];
  generic.doesNotCompile;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKwBOBLAdgcwNIRAeQCMArCAY2CgF4oBvAKCkagG0BrXALigGdl0MAulwIB7EQBsIAQzQBuOgF95dUJFggAcgFcAtgQhIc+YmQrV6TFuxBc0u-UiFRRE6XMXLSItLyjAIvABiWmjkKN5UUAA8ACpQEAAe-mgAJtzqiKiYRoQk5FAAPuraegY5JuQAfAAUGBBoBiikXDEAlFwAbiIoKVSVtAxMdQ2opMwAjALylsONpAB0KSIBGiLAAMIiOmAokvJKdEA)

The `tsconfig` I am using:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Just the whole thing overall, or something specific?

Comment: I don't understand why `generic[1]` and `generic.doesNotCompile` are invalid

Comment: string keys that are not explicitly defined need to be accessed with bracket notation. `generic['doesNotCompile']`

Comment: @ChrisHamilton - [It works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKwBOBLAdgcwNIRAeQCMArCAY2CgF4oBvAKCkagG0BrXALigGdl0MAulwIB7EQBsIAQzQBuOgF95dUJFggAcgFcAtgQhIc+YmQrV6TFuxBc0u-UiFRRE6XMXLSItLyjAIvABiWmjkKN5UUAA8ACpQEAAe-mgAJtzqiKiYRoQk5AB8ABQYEGgGKKRcMQCUXABuIigpVPm0DEwlZaikAHQpIgEaIsAAwiI6YCiS8kp0QA) if you just use `MyStringKeyObject`. The issue is the union.

Comment: Seems to be a 'strict' rule. You would have to somehow typecheck before using a string key or number key, because neither works for both types. It's like saying the parameter is `number | string`, the compiler wouldn't let you assume it's either one.

Comment: When I declare `number | string` as the key it works for both of them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder guess it depends on the environment https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ki7zyx?file=index.ts

Comment: @ChrisHamilton - [Found it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature). :-)

Comment: @ChrisHamilton I will add the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @sm3sher - I'm wondering what problem you're solving. It seems odd to define something as a string-keyed object and then use a literal property name, and similarly odd to define an umber-keyed object and then use a literal number with it. Normally, you'd derive the keys from the object itself. Where do `1` and `doesNotExist` come from? (This isn't just silly pedantry, it matters to solving the problem.)

Comment: @sm3sher I meant it won't let you use the parameter as either type unless there is something that overlaps. For example with `T extends number | string` you can't do `generic.charAt()` because you can't assume that method exists. It doesn't exist on type `number`. Same idea here, there is nothing that overlaps, so with strict enough rules, you can't assume the parameter has any properties without typechecking first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is slightly unusual because you have a pair of indexed types, but then you have hardcoded values you're using to index into them. Normally, you'd derive the keys from the object, so you wouldn't run into this problem. It arises in your case because of the explicit `1` and `doesNotExist` in the code.

The problem is that, at compile-time, `generic` may be `MyStringKeyObject` **or** `MyNumberKeyObject`. So TypeScript doesn't know which set of rules to apply, the rules for string-keyed objects or the rules for number-keyed objects.

The error for `generic.doesNotExist` makes perfect sense:

> Property 'doesNotCompile' does not exist on type 'MyStringKeyObject | MyNumberKeyObject'.
>    Property 'doesNotCompile' does not exist on type 'MyNumberKeyObject'. (2339)

That expression is valid for `MyStringKeyObject`, but not for `MyNumberKeyObject`, but `generic` might be either of them.

The error for `generic[1]` is slightly different:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '1' can't be used to index type 'MyStringKeyObject | MyNumberKeyObject'.
>    Property '1' does not exist on type 'MyStringKeyObject | MyNumberKeyObject'. (7053)

I'm a bit surprised by that the error on `generic[1]` (but then, I'm still only fairly good at TypeScript) because if you were just using `MyStringKeyObject` or `MyNumberKeyObject` (but not a union of both of them), that would be valid for either. (It's allowed for string-keyed objects because in JavaScript, you can use a number to "index" into any object, and the number gets converted to string.) Still, though, you basically have the same issue as with the other one: TypeScript needs to know what rules to apply.

The solution is to find a way to tell one member of the union from the other, and to branch accordingly. But you can't ask an object whether it's a string-indexed object or a number-indexed object at runtime. So a couple of options for you:

1. If you're going to use explicit keys like that in the code, use separate functions for `MyStringKeyObject` and `MyNumberKeyObject`. Since you're going to have to handle them separately anyway (because of the hardcoded keys), this seems logical.
2. Another approach is to add a compile-time key to the object you can use to tell them apart; a union of types where they have a common property that lets you tell them apart ("discriminate" them) is a called a discriminated union.

Here's an example of #2:

```
type MyStringKeyObject = {
    __type__: "string";
} & {
    [key: string]: boolean;
};

type MyNumberKeyObject = {
    __type__: "number";
    [key: number]: boolean;
};

const testFunction = <T extends MyStringKeyObject | MyNumberKeyObject>(generic: T): void => {
    if (generic.__type__ === "number") {
        generic[1];
    } else {
        generic.doesNotCompile; // But it does now. :-)
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKwBOBLAdgcwNIRAeQCMArCAY2CgF4oBvAKCkagH1nRJWAuKAIgGdk6DDwDcdAL5QAZLQZMA2gGtc3AakwBdbgQD2OgDYQAhmjHixddtDgA5AK4BbAhCQ58xMhWr0mLNuAguXjRHZyRROUYlFSgQpxctKF0DY1MJC1IdNAEoYAgBADE7NHIULKooAB4AFSgIAA88tAATPlgEQUw3QhJyKAAfdvt411wezwA+AAoMCDQXFFJuaoBKbgA3HRRmqgnZXxQAMygZuYXSADpWK1YqSmoeOLCeFf3fJln51FJ5AEYNMS+SQQfR8aA+d6MT7nC7NHT5Gw6YAAYR0DjAKEMgKY4nSdCAA)

In each branch of the `if`/`else`, TypeScript knows what type it's dealing with (the `if` *narrows* the type of `generic` to be one or the other of the union), so you can use those hardcoded property names.

Comment: Very well explained!

Answer (score 1):

Your rules won't allow you to assume that the parameter extends one type or the other, so you may only use properties that overlap, which is none in this case. (Correction: Technically number keys overlap since they are implicitly translated to strings).

It seems like you may want an `intersection` rather than a `union`.

```js
type MyStringKeyObject = {
  [key: string]: boolean;
};

type MyNumberKeyObject = {
  [key: number]: boolean;
};

const testFunction = <T extends MyStringKeyObject & MyNumberKeyObject>(
  generic: T
): void => {
  generic[1];
  generic['doesNotCompile'];
};
```

This would work because it says `generic` contains both string keys **and** number keys. Whereas yours says it might contain number keys **or** string keys.

With a union, you need to typecheck the parameter before assuming a certain type of key.

You can use classes alongside `instanceof` to typecheck the parameter.

```js
class MyStringKeyObject {
  [key: string]: boolean;
}

class MyNumberKeyObject {
  [key: number]: boolean;
}

const testFunction = <T extends MyStringKeyObject | MyNumberKeyObject>(
  generic: T
): void => {
  if (generic instanceof MyNumberKeyObject) {
    console.log('number key', generic[1]);
  } else if (generic instanceof MyStringKeyObject) {
    console.log('string key', generic['string']);
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid parameter', generic);
  }
};

class NumberKeyExt extends MyNumberKeyObject {}
class StringKeyExt extends MyStringKeyObject {}

const numberKey = new MyNumberKeyObject();
const numberKeyExt = new NumberKeyExt();
const stringKey = new StringKeyExt();
const stringKeyExt = new MyStringKeyObject();
numberKey[1] = true;
numberKeyExt[1] = true;
stringKey['string'] = true;
stringKeyExt['string'] = true;
testFunction(numberKey); // number key true
testFunction(numberKeyExt); // number key true
testFunction(stringKey); // string key true
testFunction(stringKeyExt); // string key true
```

`instanceof` relies on the fact that the object was created using a constructor.